# How to load response on the same page in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, response

I would like to output a response on the same page. This is what I have now :

`return new Response('ERROR! You cannot edit an inactive Payroll Period');`

but I want it to be on the same page.

```
public function editAction($payrollperiodid)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

       //$entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->find($payrollperiodid );
       $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['payrollperiodid' => $payrollperiodid, 'state' => 0]);

        if (!$entity) {

         return new Response('ERROR! You cannot edit an inactive Payroll Period');
         //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));

        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($payrollperiodid);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

When user select an inactive state to edit it gives them an error. But i don't want the output to be on the same page.

Comment: totally unclear, post some code, explain better what you want

Comment: Look at [flash message](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages)

Comment: I have edited the question and explain further. I have tried flash messages but that's not the way i want it for the user. Is a message box possible to output such??

Comment: So, a flash message is a message box, what do you mean by stay on the same page ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->addFlash()` method;

```
public function editAction($payrollperiodid)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

       //$entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->find($payrollperiodid );
       $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['payrollperiodid' => $payrollperiodid, 'state' => 0]);

        if (!$entity) {

         $this->addFlash('error', 'You cannot edit an inactive Payroll Period');
         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));

        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($payrollperiodid);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Made an answer to this affect in another one of his/her questions and apparently isn't using Sessions.....

Comment: When I use the add flash it just redirects to the payroll period page if an inactive state is selected then if I choose an active state I see the error there.

Comment: mcek is it possible to help me with another question relating to symfony

Comment: Hey Andrew can we have a chat please?

Answer (score -2):

In the argument of the Action you can use :

```
    public function editAction(Request $request, $payrollperiodid)
```

Make sure to add the use statement :

```
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

and then you can do this :

```
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success','
     The message you want to be displayed');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('NameOfTheRoute', array('parameterName' => 'parameterValue'));
```

And then in twig to get the message you can do :

```
    {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('success') %}
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ flashMessage }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

This can do the trick for you !

Comment: Did this work ? Validate my answer if this does the trick, glad to help you mate.

Comment: Sebastien is possible to help me with question relating to symfony